# What does 1 Cor 7:14 mean concerning the children being unclean or holy?

Tags: 1-corinthians, new-testament

1 Corinthians 7:14 KJB

> "For the unbelieving husband is sanctified by the wife, and the unbelieving wife is sanctified by the husband: else were your children unclean; but now are they holy."

What exactly does this mean concerning the children being unclean/holy?

Answer (score 0):

While this question may or may not be a duplicate, I do think that [my answer to this similar question addresses the same issue.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27453/in-what-sense-does-paul-use-the-word-sanctify-in-1-corinthians-714/29534?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C13.3732#29534)

There are also other thoughtful answers on the same post.